# Playstation 4 share screenshot on facebook

Tags: ps4, facebook

Is there any way for uploading to Facebook screenshots that are save on my PS4? I mean, those that I didn´t share at the moment of taking them. If so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple.

On your home screen, look for the *Capture Gallery* and launch it. From there, navigate to the screenshot you want to upload; they're categorized by game.

With your screenshot selected (highlit), you can either view it by pressing <kbd>X</kbd>, delete or copy it to a USB storage device by pressing <kbd>OPTION</kbd>, or upload it by pressing <kbd>SHARE</kbd>. The latter is what you want.

All you need to do now, is select where to upload your screenshot. Your options are Facebook, Twitter, or PSN messages.

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>*Image by me. Feel free to use as you see fit.*</sub>

Right click and select "View Image" to view image in full resolution.

Comment: How could I miss that? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mathias711 Done, I thought I did it, my bad.